# Return "/n" characters when textarea turns back from div conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am experimenting with a script from another stackoverflow post. I have a textarea element that someone can enters text. By double clicking on it, it converts to div and it keeps line breaks. When you dblclick on the div to turn back to textarea, the `<br />`s are left as are.

You can see the jsfiddle right here http://jsfiddle.net/QUFZJ/

How can I get back the text without the br's but keeping the line breaks ?

Comment: sorry ! a mistake made by speed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
boxText = $(this).html().replace(/<br\s?\/?>/g,"\n");
```

instead of

```
$(this).val().replace(/<br\s?\/?>/g,"\n");
```

You need to assign new value to boxText because You set text area value like this

```
$(this).replaceWith( '<textarea form="HTML" class="BoxText">' + boxText + '</textarea>' );
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/QUFZJ/9/)

Comment: Sorry, i updated link to jsFiddle, i put old one first time. It now works as expected as i updated link.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But why html() instead of val() ?

Comment: Because when you convert text area to div content of div is html, so you need to access with $(selector).html(), and $(selector).val() will return value of value attribute, which is in this case empty. [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) will get value from inputs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to experiment, I think you'd probably have a much more satisfying time working with `contenteditable` elements. Here's a short demo I worked up to show you how it could work.

You'll probably notice that you don't see one there in the **HTML** section. Look down in the `$.ready()` block and you'll see I actually switch between two different `div`s, as (AFAICT) you can't change a `contenteditable` once it's been added to the DOM. So my solution was to switch out what I needed. Someone let me know know if there is a way to do that, too, in case I'm overlooking something.

Note, this is not complete and while it works (seemingly) in most browsers, Opera I know has a problem with something, and I haven't really thrown that much variable text at it. It seems to work best in Chrome and Firefox. There's definitely some hamfisting going on trying to interpret pasted in markup and smooth over the different ways that each major browser interprets when you interact with a `contenteditable`.

It's a start. Check it out, see what you think.

**HTML**

```
<div class="boxtext" class="editable">Text Text Text...</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 15px 5px 5px 0;
}
.boxtext,
.boxtext .editable,
.boxtext .uneditable,
.boxtext pre.text {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.boxtext .uneditable {
    background: #ddd;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.boxtext .editable,
.boxtext .uneditable {
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.boxtext .editable {
    border: 1px solid #5794BF;
    border-right-color: #C3D4E0;
    border-bottom-color: #C3D4E0;
}
.boxtext pre.text {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    margin-top: -3px;
    background: #444;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    font-family: monospace;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    font-weight: bold;
}​
```

**Javascript**

```
(function ready($, win, doc, _c, _l, copies) {
    var $editable = $('<div class="editable" contentEditable="true">'),
        $uneditable = $('<div class="uneditable">'),
        $div = $('<div>'),
        $pre = $('<pre class="text">'),
        $doc = $(doc),
        $body,
        $boxes;

    $doc.ready(setup);

    function setup() {
        $body = $('body', doc);
        $boxes = $('.boxtext');

        $boxes.wrapInner($div.clone()).wrapInner($uneditable.clone());

        while (copies--) {
            $body.append($boxes.clone());
        }

        $boxes = $(".boxtext");

        $doc.on('click', $body, not);

        $boxes
            .on('dblclick.editable', '.editable, .uneditable', edit)
            .on('paste.editable', '.editable', paste);
    }

    function not(e) {
        !!$boxes.has(e.target).length || close.call(doc, e, true);
    }

    function close(e, call) {
        if (call) {
            $boxes.find('.editable').not(this).trigger('dblclick.editable');
        }
    }

    function edit(e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            $box = $boxes.has($this),
            $shim = $uneditable,
            type = '.uneditable';

        close.call(this, e, true);

        if ($this.is(type)) {
            $shim = $editable;
            type = '.editable';
        }

        $shim = $this.wrapInner($shim.clone()).find(type);

        $box.empty().append($shim);

        if (type == '.uneditable') {
            text.call($box[0]);
        }
    }

    function paste(e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            $target = $(e.target);

        (function a(th, ev) {
            function f(){clean.call(th, ev);}

            setTimeout(f, 1);
        })(this, e);
    }

    function clean(e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            $pres = [];

        $this.find('div > p').not(':empty').unwrap();
        $this.find(':empty').remove();
        $this.find('pre').each(function r(i, el) {
             $pres[i] = $(el).html();
        });
        $this.find('*')
            .not('h1, h2, h3, h4, p, div, br, pre, code')
            .children().unwrap();
        $this.html($.trim($this.html().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ' ')));
        $this.html($.trim($this.html().replace(/>[ ]{1,}</gm, '><')));
        $this.find('pre').each(function r(i, el) {
              $(el).html($pres[i]);
        });
        $this.find('h1, h2, h3, h4, div, p, pre').after('<br/>');
        $this.find('br:last').remove();
    }

    function text(e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            $uneditable = $this.find('.uneditable').clone(),
            $text = $pre.clone();

        $uneditable.find('div > br').unwrap();
        $uneditable.find('div, p, br').after('\n');

        $text.text('Plaintext\n---------\n' + $uneditable.text());

        $this.append($text);
    }

    function log() {
        !_c || !_l.apply || _l.apply(_c, arguments);
    }

})(jQuery, window, document, console, console.log, 5);
```

[​http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/76agk/](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/76agk/)

Comment: very nice implementation. Thank you very much for your time.